# PHP mail() not sending mail

Tags: php, linux, email, ubuntu, postfix-mta

I currently am trying to add a contact form to my site but postfix does not seem to send the mail. Here is my mail test script:

```
<?php

ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
error_reporting( E_ALL );
$from = "test@induce.tech";
$to = "mbergwall2222@gmail.com";
$subject = "PHP Mail Test script";
$message = "This is a test to check the PHP Mail functionality";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message, $headers);
echo "Test email sent";
?>
```

The script echos this out:
`Test email sent`
But no mail gets sent. I check my postfix mail log and this is what I see:

```
Jun 27 17:09:01 mbergwall2222 postfix/smtp[21196]: A0FDB41107: to=<root@mbergwall2222>, relay=none, delay=0.04, delays=0/0/0.03/0, dsn=5.4.4, status=bounced (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=mbergwall2222 type=A: Host not found)
Jun 27 17:09:01 mbergwall2222 postfix/qmgr[1915]: A0FDB41107: removed
```

Seems like there may be an issue with my hostname. If I do `hostname` in SSH, it returns `induce.tech` (this is correct, this is the domain name my server is on. Here is my postfix main.cf:

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated 
defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = induce.tech
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
inet_protocols = ipv4
local_transport = error:local delivery is disabled
smtp_helo_name = $myhostname.example.com
```

Here are my two host files:

/etc/hosts

```
# Your system has configured 'manage_etc_hosts' as True.
# As a result, if you wish for changes to this file to persist
# then you will need to either
# a.) make changes to the master file in /etc/cloud/templates/hosts.tmpl
# b.) change or remove the value of 'manage_etc_hosts' in
#     /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg or cloud-config from user-data
#
127.0.1.1 induce.tech
127.0.0.1 localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

/etc/hostname

```
induce.tech
```

**NOTE: I am using server pilot for this Ubuntu server's control panel!**

**Host: Digital Ocean**

Let me know if anyone can help! Thanks!

**EDIT: Here is my phpinfo():**
[Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/YKHmChkw)

**EDIT2: Here is the correct log file:**

```
[27-Jun-2017 17:03:50 UTC] mail() on [/srv/users/induce/apps/induce/public/portfolio/php/contact.php:9]: To: mbergwall2222@gmail.com -- Headers: From: contact@induce.tech  Reply-to: mattthefat2222@gmail.com -- Subject: test
[27-Jun-2017 17:05:48 UTC] mail() on [/srv/users/induce/apps/induce/public/portfolio/php/contact.php:9]: To: mbergwall2222@gmail.com -- Headers: From: contact@induce.tech  Reply-to: mattthefat2222@gmail.com -- Subject: Test
[27-Jun-2017 17:08:17 UTC] mail() on [/srv/users/induce/apps/induce/public/portfolio/php/contact.php:10]: To: mbergwall2222@gmail.com -- Headers: From:test@induce.tech -- Subject: PHP Mail Test script
[27-Jun-2017 17:12:12 UTC] mail() on [/srv/users/induce/apps/induce/public/portfolio/php/contact.php:10]: To: mbergwall2222@gmail.com -- Headers: From:test@induce.tech -- Subject: PHP Mail Test script
[27-Jun-2017 17:16:13 UTC] mail() on [/srv/users/induce/apps/induce/public/portfolio/php/contact.php:10]: To: mbergwall2222@gmail.com -- Headers: From:test@induce.tech -- Subject: PHP Mail Test script
[27-Jun-2017 17:16:16 UTC] mail() on [/srv/users/induce/apps/induce/public/portfolio/php/contact.php:10]: To: mbergwall2222@gmail.com -- Headers: From:test@induce.tech -- Subject: PHP Mail Test script
[27-Jun-2017 17:22:23 UTC] mail() on [/srv/users/induce/apps/induce/public/portfolio/php/contact.php:10]: To: mbergwall2222@gmail.com -- Headers: From:test@induce.tech -- Subject: PHP Mail Test script
[27-Jun-2017 17:29:35 UTC] mail() on [/srv/users/induce/apps/induce/public/portfolio/php/contact.php:10]: To: mbergwall2222@gmail.com -- Headers: From:test@induce.tech -- Subject: PHP Mail Test script
```

**EDIT3: Here is the output of `postconf -n`**

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = $myhostname, induce.tech, mbergwall2222, localhost.localdomain, localhost
mydomain = induce.tech
myhostname = induce.tech
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
```

Comment: Are you sure that message is from that script? It looks like it's trying to send a local email to `root@mbergwall2222`.

Comment: if you're hosted on digital ocean, you should already be setup to send php emails. give their support team a call.

Comment: How is your php configured? Check http://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php

Comment: @aynber I believe it is. that is all that is in the log

Comment: @datacosmos editted

Comment: so take a look in /srv/users/induce/log/induce/induce_php7.1.mail.log and check if your sendmail path is correct. I would second the comment from @aynber

Comment: @datacosmos what should the sendmail path be?

Comment: @datacosmos Looks right..... editted the question with the new log

Comment: Looking at `mydestination = $myhostname, induce.tech, mbergwall2222, localhost.localdomain, localhost` wondering where mbergwall2222 is coming from, thinking it is set in `/etc/mailname`. I second contacting the digital ocean support team, as I am unfamiliar with the heading in your `/etc/hosts` file and how it would affect your configuration.

Answer (score 1):

As you do not use a FQDN in your `/etc/hostname`, it conflicts with default configuration for postfix and how it derives the `mydomain` parameter.

> The **myhostname** parameter specifies the **fully-qualified domain name of the machine running the Postfix system**. $myhostname appears as the default value in many other Postfix configuration parameters.

> The **mydomain** parameter specifies the parent domain of $myhostname. **By
>   default, it is derived from $myhostname by stripping off the first**
>   part (unless the result would be a top-level domain).
>
> Conversely, if you specify mydomain in main.cf, then Postfix will use
>   its value to generate a fully-qualified default value for the
>   myhostname parameter.

Resources:

- http://www.postfix.org/BASIC_CONFIGURATION_README.html
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-on-ubuntu-16-04

So for example the top-level domain (TLD) of www.example.com would be `com`, where the TLD of induce.tech would be `tech`.

So to resolve the issue add a FQDN to your `/etc/hosts` file, such as `server.induce.tech`, then update the `myhostname` parameter in your `/etc/postfix/main.cf` attribute to match.

```
myhostname = server.induce.tech
```

Otherwise you will need to explicitly set the `mydomain` parameter in your `/etc/postfix/main.cf

```
mydomain = induce.tech
```

You can view the overridden settings by running `postconf -n` in your console.

Comment: Do I need to run the script on server.induce.tech or no? And also does it now send emails as example@server.induce.tech

Comment: I added mydomain = induce.tech into the main.cf, but still nothing gets sent.

Comment: Yes it will send emails as `@server.induce.tech` unless you specify `myorigin` parameter to avoid conflicting with an alternate email server. Be sure to restart postfix after making changes.

Comment: I set mydomain = induce.tech, myhostname = induce.tech, restarted postfix, still no emails are being sent.

Comment: run `postconf -n` and update your question with the result please.

Comment: Done, check the new edit